# How to Combine Bar Plots Using Two Different Data Frames Based Off of Column Data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I am rather new to R. I am trying to combine bar plots using ggplot( ) + geom_bar( ) using two different data frames with the same column (with different numbers, however).

Here is a mock of the data frames and columns I am working with:

```
DF1
##  Change
## 1    0
## 2    1
## 3    0
## 4    1
## 5    0
## 6    0
## 7    0
## 8    1
## 9    1
## 10   1

DF2     
##  Change
## 1    1
## 2    1
## 3    1
## 4    0
## 5    1
## 6    1
## 7    1
## 8    0
## 9    0
## 10   0
```

I am trying to figure out how to plot these columns as a bar plot next to each other where:

- the x-axis is just 0 and 1
- the y-axis is count/number
- there are 4 bars, 2 of DF1 and 2 of DF2

I am hoping to get something like the image attached:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Cfw.png

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be:
After some data tweaking we could use `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF1 %>% 
  mutate(group = 'DF1') %>% 
  bind_rows(DF2) %>% 
  mutate(group = replace_na(group, "DF2"), 
         Change = factor(Change)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Change, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'count', position=position_dodge()) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]